# How to save a git stash as a file or directory of files?

Tags: git

I know how to `git stash` my changes. I know how to `git stash pop` to apply those changes. Now I want to go back (remove my changes) and manually apply each one in my text editor.

How can I save the stash as a file or directory that I can open in my text editor?

Answer (score 0):

Likely you need `git diff HEAD .. <stash> > the_stash.patch`.

Internally a stash is a couple of ordinary commits, the first one for changes already added to the index (== "staged") and another with unstaged changes, on top of the former. Use `gitk --all` or a similar tool to visualize things and all other regular methods like `git show`, `git diff` etc to manipulate data in the stash.